# C++ How do I save argv to vector as strings

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, vector, argv

I am trying to save argv into a vector as strings but I keep getting the error:  `see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector<_TCHAR*[]>(_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled`

I have tried [Save argv to vector or string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361606/save-argv-to-vector-or-string) and it does not work

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> allArgs(argv + 1, argv + argc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely you need to use the non MSVS version of `main` like `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

Comment: If you're compiling with unicode, _TCHAR is a wide character which requires a std::wstring instead of a std::string.

Comment: Since you are using Visual Studio, you may not need to store those values at all. They are available throughout your applications using the [__argc, __argv, __wargv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727674.aspx) symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `std::string` doesn't have a constructor for the `_TCHAR*` type, so you can't generate a vector of strings from an array of `_TCHAR*`.

Try using as said by @NathanOliver the "normal" version of the main: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Or switch to `std::wstring`.

Note: If not compiling with unicode enabled, `_TCHAR*` may then be equivalent to `char *` and the code would not provoke any compiler errors.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
// Or: 
   // using tstring = std::basic_string<TCHAR>;
// If you have latest compiler

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<tstring> allArgs(argv + 1, argv + argc);
    return 0;
}
```

And if you would always want to use wide-strings, use this

```
  int wmain(int argc, whar_t* argv[])
  {
        std::vector<std::wstring> allArgs(argv + 1, argv + argc);
        return 0;
  }
```

Or, if you want to have ANSI only (I'd not recommend), just use old style `char` and `main`.

Comment: Bogus typedef. This should really read `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;`.