# Pass in string as command line argument

Tags: c++, command-line

I'm writing a program that makes a word ladder. A word latter is a path of getting from word A to word B. For example

head -> heal -> teal -> tell -> tall -> tail

In my main file, I'm supposed to pass in these command line arguments: file name of the .txt file that has the dictionary, a start word, a end word, and the number of steps allowed to get from a to b. I assumed you would just put the parameters on main, but its not working. I have

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[], string start, string end, int steps)
{
     return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, it gives me two warnings. The first one wants my strings to be char**. The second one says it takes only zero to two arguments.

How would I pass in a file name, two strings, and an integer from the command line?

Comment: Have you tried [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+command+line+arguments&oq=c%2B%2B+command+line+arguments&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.3199j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to figure out how command line arguments work in c++?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361606/save-argv-to-vector-or-string

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to `main` is the number of parameters on the command line.

The second parameter is an array of pointers to the parameter texts (C-Style character arrays).

If you execute your program as follows:

```
homework1.exe dictionary.txt alpha eclipse 25
```

The argument count variable will contain 5 (includes the program name).
Here is how the array of pointers will look like:

```
[0] "homework1.exe"  
[1] "dictionary.txt"
[2] "alpha"
[3] "eclipse"
[4] "25"
[5] nullptr
```

Note that the step count will be in text format and you will need to convert from text format to internal format.  One method of conversion is to use `std::istringstream`.